Sitecore 10.4 Container Installation throwing up error on Azure VM. 'Virtual Machine could not be started because required feature is not installed'
Please see below steps followed.

Created a fresh Azure VM windows 10 19045 22H2. Please refer below details. As per Sitecore documents, 10.4 container supports Windows 10 OS 1903+. Refer below image.



Azure VM size - D8s_v3



Install latest docker 4.31.1

Go to Sitecore downloads to get packages for Sitecore Container deployments. Using XM1 installation on ltsc2019

Follow the steps mentioned in installation guidelines here to run the container installation




To resolve the issue further, tried using both settings in yml file
ISOLATION=process & ISOLATION=hyperv

Still getting below error.




Is it not possible to setup Sitecore 10.4 container on Windows 10 latest OS version in Azure VM

Any idea how to resolve this issue please.




The Hyper-V and Containers features aren't enabled by default in Windows.
Open up a PowerShell in admin mode and run this command:
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All
You might need a reboot when done.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590514/how-to-enable-the-windows-10-containers-feature

Should have mentioned in the post above. This has been taken care already. Still its not working.
